# How to launch multiple instances of a process when using libuv / pyuv?

Tags: libuv

I would like to launch a process, say a command line application using libuv or pyuv. This process needs to be launched when an asynchronous event occurs. It also needs to be launched every time the event occurs.

In the examples I have referred, a process is spawned using the uv_spawn API  but it is usually done so before running the loop. When the loop is run subsequently, the process executes.

Since the scenario I described earlier already might have loop running to act on asynchronous events, I am confused as to how one might start a process ?

Further more, I would like to launch different command line applications in the case of two or more distinct events.

Please do help as this will improve my understanding of using libuv.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I checked against pyuv, asyncio and multiprocessing but i do not think the existing APIs and frameworks do not fit your requirement. Having say that there is at least one solution.

Group relevant tasks (functions) into a module and spawn a process with that module. The process may accept commands vis cli or gui or via another programs using sockets or pipes.